# How to go to new page on selection of perticular value in select statement using jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, oracle

I have one field and in that i have three values depending upon my selection web pages should open that  means if i select one value from field then it should open one web page if another one more page should open

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: you can use this function window.open("new web page");.

Comment: we can use but depending upon selection that mean that field value is more then one value so their what parameter should be sent

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're here to help if you are stuck somewhere, but not to give you the entire code from scratch.